# Dealing with special characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables `property` and `building`. In `property` table i have a field called `unitnumber` the value in this field is like `1a`, `2b` etc.. In the `building` table i have a  field called `address` which is in `PHP's` `urlencoded` format. The value will be something like `26+Dovedale+Place%2C+Parnell`

Now i want to implement a search function so that when user types `1a, 26 Dovedale` I need to pull up the result from the database.

Implemented So Far:

```
    $keyword = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $_REQUEST['keyword']);
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "-", $keyword);
    $a->rqNotEmpty('keyword', $keyword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `buildings` b left join properties p on p.buildingId=b.id 
      WHERE concat(p.floor,p.number,b.address) LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
      or concat(p.number,p.floor,b.address)  LIKE '%".$keyword."'";
```

But now the problem is when i prepare the `$keyword` variable i will get something like `1a26Dovedale` and in database after `CONCAT` the value will be somethign like `1a26+Dovedale+Place%2C+Parnell`. I cant urlencode the $keyword because the database is not in standardized form. The database my have 2 spaces between the address. So is there a way to `urldecode` mysql string ?? I am dealing with nearly 4 million records here!!

Comment: Why is the data in the DB urlencoded?  This should be done (if necessary) once the data has been pulled from the DB IMO.

Comment: @drew010: Yes you are rite.. this is done by another developer and the project has gone long way to change it to the proper way.. Now we don't have time to rewrite the bad logic. Sadly i have to live with this..

Comment: If the user types "Dovedale 1a26", do you still want to find "1a26+Dovedale+Place%2C+Parnell"?  Perhaps you should be putting each keyword in a separate WHERE condition.

Comment: @Brilliand: Yes i will add more OR conditions. I have just shown 2 conditions here..

Comment: Maybe you can urlencode your `$keyword`?  You may also try creating a `FULLTEXT` index on address if you are using MyISAM.  By searching on a wildcard like that you have to do a full table scan (maybe not a big deal if you don't have many records).

Comment: @drew010 `I cant urlencode the $keyword because the database is not in standardized form. The database my have 2 spaces between the address.` And i am dealing with nearly 4 million records here..

Comment: If you have 4 million records, your searches must be very slow, correct?  Each search has to look at all 4 million records.

Comment: @drew010: yes correct.. but not really slow.. with a loading image i am distracting the user..

Comment: You're going to spend way more time fighting with the data in this format than it would take to fix it once. This is just the beginning of your struggles, and your users are going to get awfully tired of being "distracted" by a loading image. I wish you lots of luck.

Comment: @drew010 but i think i will give `FULLTEXT` index a try while i get more suggestions here..

Comment: If possible, the FULLTEXT index may solve both issues at once.  Honestly I'm not 100% sure how FT indexing will handle the URLencoding, but you may get lucky with that.

Comment: @KenWhite one quick question is UTF-8 better than storing raw input ?? I am given the same explanation when i suggested ur idea!!

Comment: Not sure why your question was addressed to me... Anything that's usable in queries or full-text searches without having to fight to work around the data itself is better. Clean the data before storing it, and it's usable in a variety of ways. Remember the age old expression: "Garbage in, garbage out". If you store ugly data, you have data that's ugly to use. :-)

Comment: Rather than change it, perhaps add another column, copy the data over (after decoding it) and do the search against that column.  You could run a job every 10 minutes to populate any empty fields if needed.  Then over time, incrementally refactor the code to use the unencoded column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing a MySQL UDF (User Defined Function) to provide the `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` functions within MySQL. Here's the link: http://freecode.com/projects/libmysqludf